# PHP request blocked in server

Tags: php, apache, unix, block

While sending a PHP POST request to Apache server, the request is blocked by server. I am getting the forbidden error. This is very specific for some request. In the request i am sending the html data and saving the html data in the MYSQL database. I am using the unix operating system.

I am trying to save some sentence like,
`process = runtime.exec("");`
I am sending the above sentence i am getting the forbidden error, otherwise i am getting the success response.

Comment: Did you check the server's error log to see exactly why the request is denied?

Comment: Maybe add some code excerpts to your question?

Comment: Actually i am not having to access logs, i am thinking in this string "process = runtime.exec("");" some unix keyword is there like exec, may be because of that..

Comment: Same code is working for windows system..

Comment: It maybe that server block requests without user-agent header, or you send html data in url and not as multipart/form-data

Comment: no i am not sending html data via url, i am sending the post request.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server set up forbids some URL parameter values. A comparable example (for Struts), that explains why can be found here: https://www.sec-consult.com/files/20120104-0_Apache_Struts2_Multiple_Critical_Vulnerabilities.txt

You could try to trick it with some encoding (I doubt this will work) or substitute the word ".exec(" with something harmless.

Comment: i am agreed with you, but this is not the one scenario. i am experiencing in multiple scenarios. like if i am sending PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement
("select * from Emp where id=5"); this in the post request i am getting blocked also...

Comment: Actually i am using a WMD editor, in the WMD editor  <input type="hidden" id="wmd-output" name="rte1"/>  this rte1 i going to save in database. if i am putting the above string in the wmd's editors and click on save button i getting the error